show Interstitial ad after picking image from ImagePicker - flutter
I'm trying to display interstitial ad after user pick the image/video from the gallery but as soon as image is picked and I try to display ad, it throws the following error
The provided view controller is already presenting another view controller

  void pickFromGallery() async {
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? pickedVideo =
        await imagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedVideo != null) {
      initialise(pickedVideo.path);
    }
  }

  void initialise(String path) async {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
          onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {},
          onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, adError) {
            print(adError); // The provided view controller is already presenting another view controller

          });

      await interstitialAd!.show();
    } else {
      show(pickedVideo: File(path));
    }
  }


it invokes the onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent callback and throws the error
